# Vyper and strings

Tags: string, vyper

How can I manipulate strings in Vyper?
In solidity I could use Nick Johnson's string library. He's using assembly to do that. But that's not possible with Vyper as far as I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of `Vyper 0.1.0b8`, fixed-size strings are supported as `string[N]` where `N` is the maximum size of the string, like this:

```
foo: string[100]

@public
def __init__(_foo: string[100]):
    self.foo = _foo

@public
@constant
def get() -> string[100]:
    return self.foo

@public
def set(_val: string[100]):
    self.foo = _val
```

Keep pounding the refresh button at this link to keep up-to-date with new Vyper releases: https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/vyper/latest/vyper.pdf

In ^those docs you'll also find a list of relevant built-in functions (`len()`, `concat()`, etc.).